# Dump all data to just one disc

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, raid

Right now I have two HDDs set in RAID-0, each having 1TB. And I bought SSD drive that I want to connect right now.

The problem is that I only have two SATA connectors. I have power connector, but not data. I guess my motherboard (asrock p67 b3) supports just 2 sata connectors either way.

So I figured I can live with 1TB and I can disconnect one HDD, turn of raid, and connect ssd instead.

So...how can I dump all data to just one disc, and connect the other? How can I know which one can I disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disconnect one of a pair of RAID 0 drives & hope to read anything from the other.

The simple, sensible method would be to get an external USB drive & copy over your data to that. Smartest would be if it wasn't your new SSD, otherwise you'd stand the chance of blowing your only backup in the process.

Once copied, you can break the RAID if you like, then set up a new install on your SSD, with your existing data safe on another drive..